# Zabbix 5.2 storage monitoring less than n GB (OS independent)

Tags: zabbix

I am new to Zabbix. I have created monitoring for the cpu and memory. Now, I want to create a template for monitoring storage less than some GB especially for Windows or Linux which are in my network. But creating an OS independent trigger would be great.

I am following this tutorial but I think this is an older version (i am using 5.2) and the triggers are not shown in my inteface:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PS8nE2Zkal8&t=54s&ab_channel=AigarsKadikis

Is there any easy way to make this happen(maybe importing some files).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take advantage of default pre-made templates officially provided by Zabbix SIA:

- https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix/tree/master/templates/os/windows_agent
- https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix/tree/master/templates/os/linux

as zabbix agent binaries for Windows and Linux are different, mapping for them needs to happen at `host` level under zabbix web interface.

Changing trigger trasholds can be done on a template level in autodiscovery triggers section or individually directly on the host entity.

Providing a full-fledged tutotial on Zabbix triggers and treasholds is not in scope of StackOverflow answer.